# Php implode и переменная

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Оказался в затруднительной ситуации и прошу помощи.

Есть строка, полученная через implode, выглядит она примерно так: `$a+$b+$c`

Мне надо получить строку такого вида: `$abc = $a+$b+$c;`

В итоге, если подставляю `$abc = implode("+", $array);` - ничего не работает.
А если вставляю обычным текстом то же самое, то есть просто вручную делаю выражение `$abc = $a+$b+$c;` - всё работает.

Так почему же не срабатывает `implode("+", $array)`, в чём ошибка - не могу понять.

**Обновление**

Да, строка. Когда строка "$a+$b+$c" подставляется через implode, то есть вот так - $abc = implode("+", $array) - скрипт её не воспринимает.

А если вставляю просто текстом, руками $abc = $a+$b+$c; - всё воспринимается.

В переменной $array массив переменных вида $a $b $c

Comment: Да, именно так.

Мне надо сложить массивы.

Массив $abc = массив $a + массив $b + массив $c;

Comment: @veretv, оформил, как ответ.

------------------
У Вас лимит комментариев исчерпан. Если хотите добавить новый, необходимо удалить один из предыдущих, либо пишите комментарии под мои ответом.

Comment: @veretv, @romeo перенесите информацию из комментариев в исходное сообщение.

Answer (score 1):

> ["Ничего не понимаю"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vlUe8ciyh4w)
> @ Коллега

[[@veretv](/users/23461/veretv)](/users/23461/veretv), Ваша последовательность $a+$b+$c, это строка?

```
'$a+$b+$c'
```

Функция [implode()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php) конвертирует массив в строку. К примеру:

```
$data = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

var_dump(implode('+', $data)); // result: "foo+bar+baz"
```

[Смотрите результат](http://ideone.com/wgbCYZ)

Вам же, наверно, нужен `merge` (слияние). В php слиянием двух и более массивов занимается функция [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php)

```
$a = array('firstname' => 'Tom');
$b = array('lastname' => 'Sawyer');
$c = array('age' => 20);

var_dump(array_merge($a, $b, $c));
```

[Смотрите результат](http://ideone.com/wgbCYZ)

Существуют два варианта слияния: по ключу и по значению. `array_merge` - это слияние по значению. По ключу же:

```
$result = $a + $b + $c;
```

[Смотрите отличия](http://ideone.com/ZPFO0G)

**P.S.** `[]` - это короткая запись массива. Стала доступной с PHP 5.4.

Comment: По ключу нужно.
Я так и делаю - $result = $a + $b + $c;, где $a + $b + $c формируется при помощи implode. Но не работает.
А если руками прописать $result = $a + $b + $c; или сохранить в файл и тянуть оттуда - всё работает.
В этом и вопрос, почему с implode строка вида $a + $b + $c не работает на лету для $result = $a + $b + $c;

Comment: Хм... @veretv, Вы хотите, чтобы такая конструкция 

    $result = "$a + $b + $c";

Вам делала слияние по ключу? Но это строка.

К примеру, если бы в переменных `$a`, `$b`, `$c` содержались скалярные данные, то в результате вы получили следующее:

    $a = 'foo';
    $b = 'bar';
    $c = 'baz';
    
    // используются двойные кавычки, чтобы можно было подставить переменные
    // т.е. назовём их плейсхолдерами (заполнителями)
    $result = "{$a} + {$b} + {$c}";
    
    var_dump($result); // result: "foo + bar + baz"

[Смотрите результат](http://ideone.com/na8f9R)

Comment: Всё равно не едут лыжи. Ладно, благодарю за помощь, скорее всего, надо будет искать другое решение.

Comment: @veretv, если вместо скалярных данных,там будут массивы:

    $a = array('firstname' => 'Tom');
    $b = array('lastname' => 'Sawyer');
    $c = array('age' => 20);
    
    $result = "$a + $b + $c";

то, если задан режим протоколирования всех ошибок `error_reporting(E_ALL)` ([почитать](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.error-reporting.php)) на экран выведет ошибку `[E_NOTICE] Array to string conversion` ([почитать](http://php.net/manual/ru/errorfunc.constants.php)). Если режим более щедящий, то резудьтатом будет строка `"Array + Array + Array"`.

[Смотрите результат](http://ideone.com/gu3QzR

Comment: > Всё равно не едут лыжи.

Ведь глупая ситуация, согласитесь. В Вашем вопросе кроется какая-то "элементарщина" и мы вместе не можем никак её "порешить". Я Вам и про merge и про конкатенацию, в общем, про всё уже рассказал.

Возможно, у Вас какой-то кусок кода приходит в виде строки, то можно через `eval` ([почитать](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.eval.php)), либо закешировать в php-файл и выполнить его.

Comment: @veretv, выложите Ваш кода, к примеру, на [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/). Возможно, тогда мы сможем решить Вашу проблему.

Comment: @veretv, может быть, чисто гипотетически, вы [`array_sum`][1] ищете?

    $array = array (1, 2, 3);
    $abc = array_sum($array);
    // $abc === 6


  [1]: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-sum.php